# nth-of-type keeps changing on a webpage, how do I get iMacros to automatically adapt to this change?

Tags: imacros

I'm using **iMacros for Firefox** to automate commenting on a website. The website is a photo sharing site and this script loads up a profile, locates the first comment box for the first picture, types a comment, and then submits. This is the script for one comment:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#user-content-posts>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#user-content-posts>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TEXTAREA" CHARS=[comment]
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#user-content-posts>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=60
```

The problem is, let's say I open up a browser the next day and decide to run the script, for some reason the script does not work now because iMacros can't find `DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>` anymore, the correct location is now `>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>`.

So basically all the 3's turn to 2's and then the script works fine again. But then another day if I log back on and open another browser, all of a sudden the script doesn't work anymore and I have to change the last 2's back to 3's and then everything works again

How do I get around this? Is there a way to have iMacros automatically adapt to this? I don't know why nth-of-type changes from (3) to (2) randomly. It sometimes happens when the profile uploads a new picture. I plan to run this script 24/7 so I would need it to adapt whenever a change like this happens. Anyone good with iMacros and can help that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workaround:

```
SET div3 #user-content-posts>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>
SET div2 #user-content-posts>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="{{div3}}TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="{{div3}}TEXTAREA" CHARS=[comment]
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="{{div3}}BUTTON" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="{{div2}}TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="{{div2}}TEXTAREA" CHARS=[comment]
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="{{div2}}BUTTON" BUTTON=0

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

WAIT SECONDS=60
```

Comment: Hi there, this has worked but the problem is that the iMacros would post comments on both pictures, how do I make it so that it only posts on the picture closest to the top of the page? i.e. the latest picture uploaded

Comment: I would suggest applying the [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) , because some other ideas (how to work around) may appear only by means of testing on the real web page but not at random.